# Pasar de filas a columnas en Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla muy parecida a esta (la id no es clave primaria):

```
    id    nombre producto    atributo
    1     Camiseta           Color: Negro
    1     Camiseta           Tam: XL
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo pasar de la tabla anterior a una así:

```
    id    nombre producto    atributos
    1     Camiseta           Color: Negro, Tam: XL
```

También me gustaría saber si es posible llegar a esto:

```
    id    nombre producto    atributo1       atributo2
    1     Camiseta           Color: Negro    Tam: XL
```

Una cosa a tener en cuenta es que no todos los productos tienen atributo, unos pueden tener un atributo, dos, o quince.

Lo he intentado con crosstab pero no sé utilizar la función. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: En realidad la columna atributo debería ser una tabla y necesitarías una table de relación "producto_atributos". Producto -> producto_atributos -> Atributo.

Comment: Comparte tus intentos.

Comment: Está ya en una tabla. Esto es una vista que he creado para que el cliente lo vea todo en un sólo lugar y la vista importa columnas de muchas tablas.

@sstan No compartí el intento del `crosstab()` porque el problema es que no sé cómo se utiliza la función. Intenté hacer algo parecido a 
`select  id, "nombre producto", crontab(atributo)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select string_agg(col,',') from my_table
```

Ejemplo:

```
select id, nombre_producto, string_agg(atributo,',')
from productos where nombre_producto='Camiseta'
```

te daría:

```
id  nombre_producto string_agg
1   Camiseta        Color: Negro, Tam: XL
```

Comment: Va perfecto en el primero de los casos, aunque no añadí la cláusula del where para que lo hiciera en toda la tabla.

¿Sabrías llegar a la segunda solución?